# highlight some words of a string inside richtextbox in ms access form

Tags: ms-access, richtextbox, highlight, cpu-word

I have a ms access form with a richtextbox and a textbox.
For instance there is below statement:
"Nutritional science studies how the body breaks food down (catabolism) and how it repairs and creates cells and tissue (anabolism). Catabolism and anabolism combined can also be referred to as metabolism. Nutritional science also examines how the body responds to food"

I want to is highlight words in richtextbox (some words for example: science anabolism and  metabolism) that I have typed into textbox. 
Notice: I know how to highlight one word but I want to highlight several words
Thank you

Comment: Why can't you highlight whichever words you want with the richtext toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Consider some version of this:

```
Dim aryWords As Variant, x As Integer, strText As String
aryWords = Split("Axxx Bxxx Cxxx", " ")
strText = "LAKJF Axxx kdjf Bxxx KLJALKj Cxxx"
For x = LBound(aryWords) To UBound(aryWords)
    strText = Replace(strText, aryWords(x), "<b>" & aryWords(x) & "</b>")
Next
Debug.Print = strText
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much.